# Plenty of reading errors in Python with Adafruit Library for DHT22 on a Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, temperature, raspberry-pi-zero, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm using a DHT22 temperature and humidity sensor with a Raspberry Pi Zero W V1.1 to log temperature and humidity. I use Python and Adafruit library (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_DHT) and even that I'm able to read the data, I get plenty of reading errors. Just as an example, this is a log of the errors reported in a few minutes of logging (reading is done once every 2 seconds):

```
2021/09/14 00:00:32 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:00:48 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:01:09 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:01:16 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:01:41 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:01:41 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:01:41 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:01:55 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:02:04 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:02:25 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:02:34 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:02:41 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:02:48 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:03:09 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:03:16 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:03:16 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:03:32 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:03:39 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:04:02 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:04:16 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:04:23 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:04:39 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
2021/09/14 00:04:39 A full buffer was not returned. Try again.
```

I have googled the issue and I have found plenty of similar cases. It seems to be that the problem lies on Adafruit library (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_DHT). Previous library (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT) according to several people seems that worked better (but not 100%) but anyway now it is deprecated.

Anybody knows a library to read DHT22 without glitches ?

Thanks !